# How to extract files from an inaccessible partition?

Tags: fedora, boot, partition, data-recovery, system-recovery

I cannot boot into my installed Fedora 37 after moving around partitions. I have spent a week trying to fix the issue so have decided to cut my losses and assume I'll never get back into it.

I have been booting Fedora 37 from a live USB since the issue occurred and I can see my old OS's partition on Disks/Gparted so I know the data is still there.

What is a way to extract the files from within the partition using a live boot?

Comment: Use `testdisk`. Is very good.

Comment: Dependin on what failed when you moved around partitions you could try to mount the partitions **readonly**. If this fails you can try to use data recovery software like `testdisk`/`photorec`. IMPORTANT: Make sure no data is written to the disk, maybe create a copy of the raw disk and work with the copy only.